# SELECT con ROWNUM, ORBER BY y FOR UPDATE sobre 2 tablas da Error ORA-02014

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

Necesito utilizar una consulta en Oracle 12 con un Order by, un rownum y además necesito que sea "For Update", pero parece que es incompatible con la  clausula For Update.
Lo que necesito es ejecutar la misma consulta en dos nodos diferentes, cada una con distinta ordenación (por mismo campo en un nodo ascendente y en el otro descendente) para poder optimizar los procesos de modificación de estos datos.
La consulta sería de este estilo:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT CAMPO_11, 
  FROM TABLA_1 C, 
       TABLA_2 S
 WHERE (C.CAMPO_12 = (SELECT COUNT(1) 
                        FROM TABLA_2
                       WHERE CAMPO_21 = C.CAMPO_13 
                         AND CAMPO_22='x')
   AND C.CAMPO_13   = S.CAMPO_21
   AND C.CAMPO_14    = 'X'
   AND S.CAMPO_23  = 'ZZZ')
   ORDER BY CAMPO_12)
WHERE ROWNUM <=2 
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
;
```

pero da error 02014. 00000 -  "cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc."

¿Alguien sabe como hacer esta query para que funcione?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no se entiende nada de lo que tratas de hacer...